# Why doesn't this simple roll die code 'print' anything?

Tags: python

The text book has this sample code written word for word, but when I press shift + enter, there is no output and I don't know why.

I have tried putting n = 10, both in the paranthesis and again by assigning the value 10 to the variable.

```
import random

def rollDie():
    return random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6])

def rollN(n):
    result = ''
    for i in range(n):
         result = result + str(rollDie())
    print(result)
```

I am not getting any sort of output or error message. It says if I run rollN(10) I should get 10 random integers from 1-6, but I cannot get anything.

Comment: Are you calling  `rollN` somewhere?

Comment: You define two functions but never call them

Comment: You have to run ` rollN(10)` at the end of your code

Answer (score 2):

You are not calling the rollN() function. Try this:

```
import random

def rollDie():
    return random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6])

def rollN(n):
    result = ''
    for i in range(n):
         result = result + str(rollDie())
    print(result)

def main():
    rollN(10)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

"I have tried putting n = 10,"

The problem here is that you have two functions ***defined*** but they are never ***executed***. Thus, even by putting n = 10 in the function parameter, the function is still not being actually called upon.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
import random
def rollDie(m):
    return random.choices(range(m))[0]

def rollN(n,m=6):
    print(" ".join(map(str,[rollDie(m) for i in range(n)])))

print(rollN(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem with this code here is that you are defining the functions, but not calling them anywhere. Try this:

```
import random

def rollDie():
    return random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6])

def rollN(n):
    result = ''
    for i in range(n):
         result = result + str(rollDie())
    print(result)

rollN(10)
```

If you wanted to you could shorten the code to:

```
import random

def rollN(n):
    result = ''
    for i in range(n):
        result = result + str(return random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6]))
    print(result)

rollN(10)
```